# Missing EntityTypeConfiguration Solution for EF7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

please can you help me with missing class EntityTypeConfiguration in EF7?
I have this idea:

```
 public class SmartModelBuilder<T> where T : class {

    private ModelBuilder _builder { get; set; }
    private Action<EntityTypeBuilder<T>> _entityAction { get; set; }

    public SmartModelBuilder(ModelBuilder builder, Action<EntityTypeBuilder<T>> entityAction)
    {
        this._builder = builder;
        this._entityAction = entityAction;

        this._builder.Entity<T>(_entityAction);
    }
}
```

I can pass config via fluent api like this:

```
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
     {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);  


        BlogConfig b = new BlogConfig(builder);   
     }

 public class BlogConfig
 {
      private ModelBuilder _builder {get; set;}
      public BlogConfig(ModelBuilder builder)
      {
           this._builder = builder; 
           new SmartModelBuilder<Blog>(_builder, entity => entity.Property(b => b.Url).Required()); 

      }
 }
```

Or check create static metod in BlogConfig and run this metod in OnModelCreating..
I have this not tested..

Comment: How did you manage this in the end?

Comment: Hi, not tested - see top my later edit.